# UINavigationController animating view but not header

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

Is there a way to transition through views in the navigation controller without the header animating?

I'm creating an app which asks users questions, when they click next a new question is pushed onto the NavigationStack and is animated in.  But the titlebar is also animated.  The title on the title bar does not change so is there a way to stop the title bar from animating?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a paged `UIScrollView` instead of the `UINavigationController`. Setup your view in IB with a `UINavigationBar` on top of the view and right below place the `UIScrollview` and let the user scroll through your questions this way.

Comment: I hadn't thought of a paged UIScrollView, I've already got most of my app structured using the UINavigationController so its too late to change it now, but something to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could stop animation with:

```
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
```

and ensure you set the title for the pushed view controller to the (same) correct title; e.g. in the detailed view controller's `viewDidLoad` method do:

```
self.title = @"title";
```

Now, you could add a custom `initWithTitle:` method say, to you detailed view controller custom class to pass-in the title you require to set if the title need to change, not like you mention in your question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: setting the title isn't a problem, I do set the title in each viewController.  The doesn't change and is the same for all viewControllers in the navigation tree.  What I'm trying to do is stop the header animating and just animate the view when its pushed/poped to/from the stack.

Comment: Er, it should work no? If you push your detailed view controller (as in the code snip) with *animated* set to `NO` it doesn't animate if you ensure the title field is the same.  I'll try and find my skeleton project I used to test this out..

Comment: When the _animated_ is set to NO nothing is animated.  I still want the main view to animate in, I just want the header not to animate.

Comment: I see, a scroll view type of behaviour would have been the way to proceed - I see in another comment, it's too late for this? Because you can set the content offset for a scrollview, this is really the way to implement you behaviour right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (in my case, I have the same title in every child that I add to the nav controller so animating the title looks funny)

I solved this by adding the title directly the nav controller, and setting the title of child controllers to nil

```
UINavigationController *nav_controller;

UILabel *lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...]
// Modify your title here

[nav_controller.view addSubview:lbl_title];

UIViewController *vc_child;
vc_child.title = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there's any straight forward solution to this problem. But i feel it is achievable. You can have one navigation controller. When you push the next view from navigation controller, you may have to take refuge of some custom animations.

What you can do i think is, you can add the next view as subview at a frame where

```
x = 350( anything beyond the view frame i.e 320, assuming iphone) , 
y = 0 , 
width = 320 and 
height = view height - 20 (20 is the height of navigation bar)
```

you can add your next view as a subview to the existing navigation controller instead of pushing the view from the navigation controller and give some custom animations to the view while changing x values from 350 to 0.

This will seem like you are pushing the view but you are just creating the effect of it by adding as a subview.

Hope this may give an approach towards your solution.